# iphdr struct src and dest unexpected

Tags: c

I was trying to understand the iphdr struct and I don't understand what src and dest represent. For instance I have a packet sniffer that takes the packet and passes it into an iphdr struct. Running netcat with `nc 127.0.0.1 7999` and `nc -l 127.0.0.1 7999` I get the result 16777343 for the src and dest. Am I forgetting a conversion or something?

Comment: Look at the hex representation of that number and see if you can figure it out

Comment: Are you aware of representation of numbers as four bytes in decimal representation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1 * 256 * 256 * 256 + 127` is 16777343.
I think that demonstrates the needed conversion nicely.
It is close to the hexadecimal representation, just that each bytes value is then shown in decimal.